# How to scope nested association in Rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord, scope

I have the following code using Formtastic.

```
- if can? :update, @workout
  = semantic_form_for ew.exercise, :url => user_exercise_path(@user, ew.exercise) do |exercise|
    %table
      %thead
        %tr
          %th.reps Reps
          %th.weight Weight
      %tbody
        = exercise.semantic_fields_for :log_entries do |log_entry|
          = render 'log_entry_fields', :f => log_entry
    .links
      = link_to_add_association 'Add Set', exercise, :log_entries
    = exercise.actions do
      = exercise.action :submit
```

Given that, my problem is that log_entries renders log_entries for every log entry related to an exercise.

E.g, if Bob is recording log entries for benchpress, and Hope is recording log entries for benchpress then with this form both those log_entries are going to render. What I want it to do is be scoped only for the current_user's log_entries against that exercise.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the following modification:

```
= exercise.semantic_fields_for :log_entries, exercise.object.log_entries.for_user(@user) do |log_entry|
```

Everything after the comma is new. I created a class method on my `log_entry.rb` with the following:

```
def self.for_user(user)
  where(:user_id => user.id)
end
```